# Add active class on label if selected option value in edit mode?

Tags: jquery, html

I have use material design form but problem is after click to add active class in label. If you possible that add active class if selected any value on edit mode. I have try to add active class in label but this apply to all label how to specific select label add active class.'

HTML:

```
 <div class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column column_container">
     <div class="md-form dropdown"> 
         <label for="login_type" class="control-lbl">Login Type <span>*</span> <div class="tooltip help"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i><span class="tooltiptext">Attendee needs to enter email and pin in case login is required. </span></div></label>
          <select required="" class="form-control select-form valid" type="text" name="login_type" id="login_type" aria-invalid="false">
            <option value="" selected=""></option>
            <option value="1">Required</option>
            <option value="2">Optional</option>
            <option selected="" value="0">No Login</option>
          </select>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var r1 = $( "select option:selected" ).text();
    if (r1.length != 0){
        $('label.control-lbl').addClass("active");  
        }
    else{
        $('label.control-lbl').removeClass("active");   
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[attribute*=value]` selector in JQuery. Modify your selector to this

```
$("label[for*='login_type']").addClass("active");
```

More [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

---

**Update**

```js
$("select").each(function() {
  $(this).on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).children("option:selected").text() == "Optional") {
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .children("label")
        .addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column column_container">
  <div class="md-form dropdown">
    <label for="login_type" class="control-lbl">Login Type <span>*</span> <div class="tooltip help"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i><span class="tooltiptext">Attendee needs to enter email and pin in case login is required. </span></div></label>
    <select required="" class="form-control select-form valid" type="text" name="login_type" id="login_type" aria-invalid="false">
      <option value="" selected=""></option>
      <option value="1">Required</option>
      <option value="2">Optional</option>
      <option selected="" value="0">No Login</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column column_container">
  <div class="md-form dropdown">
    <label for="login_type" class="control-lbl">Login Type <span>*</span> <div class="tooltip help"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i><span class="tooltiptext">Attendee needs to enter email and pin in case login is required. </span></div></label>
    <select required="" class="form-control select-form valid" type="text" name="login_type" id="login_type" aria-invalid="false">
      <option value="" selected=""></option>
      <option value="1">Required</option>
      <option value="2">Optional</option>
      <option selected="" value="0">No Login</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but problem is same page to use three time select dropdown so that time is not right way to return three time label

Comment: Can you work with indexes also?? `$("label[for*='login_type']")[0]` `$("label[for*='login_type']")[1]` `$("label[for*='login_type']")[2]`?? @user9595480

Comment: I have not use these type but i have try another way in below $(this).parent().children("label").addClass("active"); but still is not working